# http://127.0.0.1:8000/ This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Tags: django, windows

I created my program in pycharm. It is a series of questions for the user that adds their inputs and get a result from it, pretty basic stuff.
I want to share the program with my colleagues, but they are not interested in the coding part, they want to see how it works. So I thought did a little research and decided to test Django.
I installed django 4.2.10 and followed chatgtp's steps.
Now I have the following folders and files:

```
HYSPI_project/
|-- HYSPI_app/  # Your Django app
|-- HYSPI_project/  # Your Django project folder
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- asgi.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
|-- python
```

Everything looks good, but when I run python manage.py runserver, the only thing that happens is that my program starts, in bash (mamba).

If I try to open  http://127.0.0.1:8000 in the browser it says the site cannot be reached.

I have verified everything, connection, firewall, and all suggestions from chatgpt.

Maybe the problem is in one of my files, manage.py, urls.py, settings.py, but when I ask chatgpt it always says that everything looks ok, and asks me for more information on the error when running runserver, but there is no error, it is running the program.

Maybe I misunderstood what Django is.

All I wanted was to share my program without having to ask my colleagues to create the same environment I have.

I have described what I tried in the comment above

Comment: Did you run Django? `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: yes, when I run python manage.py runserver my program starts running in the terminal..

(la_39) C:\Users\jsteinbach\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\HYSPI_beta>python manage.py runserver
WARNING:root:No DATABASE_URL environment variable set, and so no databases setup
WARNING:root:No DATABASE_URL environment variable set, and so no databases setup
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
INFO:django.utils.autoreload:Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Biosphere database already present!!! No setup is needed << this part is my program

Comment: 1) You should edit the question to include extra information, not in comments, so that you can format it well. 2) You didn't even tell you are on Windows, until that's showed in the comment as Windows file path. Then the "terminal", "bash (mamba)" things can make more sense to readers.

Answer (score 0):

To share your `Django` project locally, you need to run it within your virtual environment using the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then you will have to find your `local IP` by running the following command to `cmd`

```
ipconfig
```

The way to access your app from another PC within your local network is by browsing to

```
YOUR_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS:8000
```

P.S. This method is intended only for debugging purposes. If you want the app to be in production mode, you have to deploy it on IIS (Internet Information Services) for Windows.

Check this out:
https://adrianjnkns.medium.com/django-on-iis-b33574dbd510

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly when I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 the same thing happens, my program starts running in the prompt and I cannot connect to http://127.0.0.1:8000  or any other similar address

Comment: Share your project to GitHub.

Comment: wfastcgi package has been deprecated by Microsoft, so that FastCGI approach mentioned in that link should be avoided.